# Unable to remove label in GMAIL PHP API

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I am working on a project where I have several labels associated with every email. I want to remove the labels using gmail PHP API. I have followed the documentation and I have done all the steps. But, I do not know why I get Error, when I try to remove the label.

This is the code that is associated with the project. Please help me with any thoughts.

```
  $client_id = 'aoppedisano@tecnavi.com';
  $service_account_name = 'anthony@teak-truck- 130612.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
  $key_file_location = 'anthony.p12';
  $userid_from='aoppedisano@tecnavi.com';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  var_dump($client);
  $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'));
  $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
  if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
 }
 $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
 $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_name,
  array(
 /*     
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
*/
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
 ),
   $key
   );
   //var_dump($cred);
  $cred->sub=$userid_from; //<-- Important!
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

  if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
 }
 $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
 $messageId=$_REQUEST["id"];
 $userId = 'me';
 $optParamsGet = [];
 $optParamsGet['format'] = 'full';
 $message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
 $labelsToRemove=$_REQUEST['label'];
 $labelsToAdd=[];
 $message=modifyMessage($service,$userId, $messageId, $labelsToAdd,         $labelsToRemove);



    function modifyMessage($service, $userId, $messageId, $labelsToAdd,  $labelsToRemove) {
     $mods = new Google_Service_Gmail_ModifyMessageRequest();
     $mods->setAddLabelIds($labelsToAdd);
     $mods->setRemoveLabelIds($labelsToRemove);
    try {
     $message = $service->users_messages->modify($userId, $messageId, $mods);
     print 'Message with ID: ' . $messageId . ' successfully modified.';
     return $message;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
     print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is the error that I got An error occurred: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/156d80449f28bd94/modify: (403) Insufficient Permission

Answer (score 0):

As given in [Standard Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/standard-error-responses) for Google APIs, `403: insufficientPermissions` error code means that the authenticated user does not have sufficient permissions to execute this request.

To delete labels, you should have this scope code in your permissions:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels
```

For more details about scopes, please go through [Choose Auth Scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes).

Comment: Hi Teyam,Thank you for answering my question. I tried these two ways Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: <?php

$client_id = 'aoppedisano@tecnavia.com';
$service_account_name = 'anthony@teak-truck-130612.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'anthony.p12';
$userid_from='aoppedisano@tecnavia.com';
$client = new Google_Client();
var_dump($client);
$client-  >setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels'));
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
//var_dump($client->getAccessToken());
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
//var_dump($key);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_name,
  array(
/*   
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
*/
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels'
  ),

Comment: But both of them gave me erro. First one gave me error on tokenresfresh and second one gave me same error as the one I posted. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to initially authorize your app with Gmail? Please note that all requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. You may refer to [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) for more information and to help you get started with authorization.

Comment: Hi Teyam, I do not know the answer. Do I need to initialize my app. I did something to get the service account up. I do not know. Do you know how to configure this app through service account?

Comment: Regarding service accounts, this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) which is for PHP will help.